# Iterate over two list to get index location

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find efficient approach to traverse two lists and return indexes of the second list based on the match between the elements in both the list. The indexes are then used to lookup data from another array so second list essentially holds position for the array.

Both List are of type RowType where

```
public class RowType 
{
    public int Type; //Acts as a group
    public int SubType; //Specific classification of the type
}
```

My current approach is to iterate over the first list and then for each element, iterate over the second list comparing Type or Type\Subtype combination to get the index. This is essentially O(n*m) which is dragging down the overall performance.

List1 can contains combination of RowType elements where **only Type is specified or Type and SubType both**.

List2 contains elements which has **both Type and SubType**.

In example below T1 and T2 are two types and R1 to R16 are SubType. SubType are unique across Type. So R1 is a subtype for T1 then no other type will have R1 as subtype.

```
Input
    List<RowType> list1 = new List<RowType>(){ T1, T2, RT3 }
    List<RowType> list2 = new List<RowType>(){ RT1, RT3, RT6, RT7, RT9 }

    where 
    RT1 -> Type = T1, SubType = R1
    RT3 -> Type = T3, SubType = R3
    RT6 -> Type = T1, SubType = R6
    RT7 -> Type = T2, SubType = R7
    RT9 -> Type = T4, SubType = R9

Expected Output
    0, 1, 2, 3  

Index 0 since T1 is Type for RT1
Index 2 since T1 is Type for RT6
Index 3 since T2 is Type for R7
Index 1 since RT3 matches RT3
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can first iterate the original list and add each entry into a dictionary where the key is the element in the list and the value is the index. As long as you override `GetHashCode` properly in the `RowType` you should be able to use a `Dictionary<RowType, int>`. After that, iterate the second list and lookup each item in the dictionary to determine its index. This would yield O(n + m) but will obviously have more memory footprint.

Comment: You may find a solution with better run-time performance characteristics, but since determining the index of your elements requires them to be visited at least once, the most efficient class of solutions will yield O(n + m).

Comment: Thanks @Ameen. I considered that approach and as you mentioned concerned with memory footprint. I will give it a try and see how it performs under load.

Comment: We tried another options and that seems to work for us. We created two int arrays for type and subtype, the list of type and subtypes are predefined.

Comment: We iterate over input list and mark the int array with a magic value depending on the element. Second list is iterated and a match is found based on the magic value. This improves the response time significantly at the cost of two int array for each operation.